# Total number of items given equal probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

You are given a bucket with apples and oranges. There are two apples, and the rest oranges. Four children uniformly randomly pick a fruit from the bucket. The probability that all four children pick oranges is A and the probability that two of the four children  pick the apples is B. After that, you realize at A = B. What's the total amount of fruits (apples + oranges) in the bucket?

#### My Attempt

- Total number = ( N )
- Number of apples = 2
- Number of oranges = ( N - 2 )

$$
A = \frac{{\binom{{N-2}}{{4}}}}{{\binom{N}{4}}}
$$

$$
B = \frac{{\binom{2}{2} \times \binom{{N-2}}{{2}}}}{{\binom{N}{4}}}
$$

Given that ( A = B ), we can equate these probabilities:

$$
\frac{{\binom{{N-2}}{{4}}}}{{\binom{N}{4}}} = \frac{{\binom{2}{2} \times \binom{{N-2}}{{2}}}}{{\binom{N}{4}}}
$$

Solving, I get that N = 6. But when I use this value to calculate A and B, I realize that they're not equal. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Oh, I see they're equal, thanks. Do you agree with the general approach used to come to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N$ would be $8$, not $6$.
$$\begin{align*}
&{{N-2} \choose 4} = {{N-2} \choose 2} \\\\
\Rightarrow \;\;\; & N - 2 = 4 + 2 \\\\
\Rightarrow \;\;\; & N = 8 \\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Below we are solving the given equation:
$$ \binom {N - 2}{4} = \binom {2}{2} \cdot \binom {N - 2}{2}. $$
Trivially, $\binom {2}{2} = 1$, so
$$ \binom {N - 2}{4} = \binom {N - 2}{2}. $$
By definition, this is saying
$$ \frac {\left( N - 2 \right)!}{4! \, \left( N - 6 \right)!} = \frac {\left( N - 2 \right)!}{2! \, \left( N - 4 \right)!}. $$
Cancelling common factors, rearrrangement yields
$$ \frac {\left( N - 4 \right)!}{\left( N - 6 \right)!} = \frac {4!}{2!}, $$
whence we derive
$$ \left( N - 4 \right) \left( N - 5 \right) = 12. $$
Expand the left-hand side. Rearrange the terms to see
$$ {N}^{2} - 9 N + 8 = 0. $$
Factoring should be easy:
$$ \left( N - 1 \right) \left( N - 8 \right) = 0. $$
Since $N - 2 \ge 0$, we finally conclude that $N = 8$, as Haris has suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! I struggled with evaluating the factorials, and this helped a lot :)